# How do I get an item into a hidden form field in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

I guez whatever I'm unable to do is possible for many of us here. I have a form and a view.
**I'd like to pass a value from a forloop into the form silently as a hidden field.**

```
def new_issue_book(request,pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewIssueForm(request.POST,school= request.user.school,pk=pk)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['borrower_id']
            form.save(commit=True)
            books = Books.objects.filter(school = request.user.school).get(id=pk)
            semest = Student.objects.filter(school = request.user.school).get(student_id=name).semester
            departm = Student.objects.filter(school = request.user.school).get(student_id=name).depart
            Books.Claimbook(books)
            return redirect('view_issue')
    else:
        form = NewIssueForm(school= request.user.school,pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'new_issue_book.html', {'form': form})
```

The model form

```
class NewIssueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,*args, pk,school, **kwargs):
        super(NewIssueForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['borrower_id'].queryset = Student.objects.filter(school=school)

        self.fields['book_id'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Books.objects.filter(id = pk))

    class Meta:
        model = Issue
        fields = ['book_id','borrower_id']
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/#hiddeninput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you.

```
class NewIssueForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,*args, pk,school, **kwargs):
        super(NewIssueForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['borrower_id'].queryset = Student.objects.filter(
            school=school)

        self.fields['book_id'].initial = pk #Sets the field with the pk and it's hidden again

    class Meta:
        model = Issue
        fields = ['book_id','borrower_id']
        widgets = {
            'book_id':forms.TextInput(attrs={"'type':'hidden'}),

        }
```

Comment: Django has `HiddenInput`, there is no reason to make a `TextInput` and override the type to hidden.